# Splittig an object into its "view" and "editor"

Tags: php, oop

Normally, I split my objects into "views" that load their data, and "editors" that inherit from the views and can edit the data in the database.
My problem is that I have a inheritance structure like this:

```
parentView
childView1 extends parentView
childView2 extends parentView

parentEditor extends parentView
childEditor1 extends parentEditor // PROBLEM HERE
childEditor2 extends parentEditor // PROBLEM HERE
```

Obviously, the inheritance of the childEditors is not the best, because I would need to copy code from the childViews.

Is there a better solution? 
I am sure there is a lot on this topic on the Net, but I am missing the right "keyword" to find them.

PS: Developing in PHP

Comment: What version of php do you plan your application run on? If you are on php 5.4+ maybe trairs could help you out (they are basically a compiler assisted copy-and-paste)

Comment: I've read about traits. Is this a "clean" solution? Unfortunately, the current PHP version used is 5.3.2 :(

Comment: No it's not. Writing correct OOP-code should eliminate the need of doing this.

Comment: I'm afraid the answer depends on who you ask, maybe composition or a decorator might be better than using inheritance for this.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a bad way to extend classes and the hierarchy does not make any sense.

You say that you split the code into views and editors. That is okey, but should mean that no code from the views are used in the editors and vice versa, when building a schema like this.

The way I see it, it would make a whole lot more sense to have a abstract class that each view extends. Then having the editor extend the view again. The editor is then connected to the view in a more OOP-sensible way.

Comment: That may make sense, but how does it help me with my problem above? if childEditors extends childViews, I would need to copy the code in childEditor1 and childEditor2

Comment: @schlimpf - The different editors should not have anything to do with each other. At least that is how I understand it from what you write. Each editor extends a view and only that editor can change/edit data in the database. What need does an editor have to access data and methods from another editor?

Comment: Sorry for the missunterstanding. Of course the editors do not need to access data from each other. What I mean is, that the code of childEditor1 and childEditor2 is almost the same and thats why I tried to inherit from the parentEditor

Comment: Do you need to inherit? You could simply create an instance for the editor (inside the childeditor) and load all the common methods from there.